# Flatten fields in request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I have simple request:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Request
{
    private Address address;
    private Name name;
}
```

where `Address` and `Name`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address
{
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Name
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

and easy controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @PostMapping(path = "data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody Request request)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("1234");
    }
}
```

To make a request I have to use postman with request body like:

```
{
    "address": {
        "postalCode":"aaaa",
        "city":"bbb"
    },
    "name": {
        "firstName": "tom",
        "lastName": "xyz"
    }
}
```

And my question: is there any way to "flatten" this request to simple attributes:

```
{
    "city":"bbb"
    "postalCode":"aaaa",
    "firstName": "tom",
    "lastName": "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate with `@JsonUnwrapped` the fields `address` and `name` in your `Request` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Request
{
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Address address;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Name name;
}
```

Here is a small sample of code:

At first serialize the Request to json string:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

Address address = new Address("123435", "Athens");
Name name = new Name("John", "Doe");
Request request = new Request(address, name);
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
System.out.println(s);
```

Console output:

```
{"postalCode":"123435","city":"Athens","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

And then deserialize the json string to Request object:

```
Request request1 = mapper.readValue("{\"postalCode\":\"12345\",\"city\":\"Athens\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"}", Request.class);
System.out.println(request1.getAddress().getPostalCode());
System.out.println(request1.getAddress().getCity());
System.out.println(request1.getName().getFirstName());
System.out.println(request1.getName().getLastName());
```

and the console output:

```
12345
Athens
John
Doe
```